# Info about re-alloc of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a question... If I have for example one NSMutableArray and if I use it... with for example 100 object... if I use this code:

```
mutablearray=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and add at the array others 100 objects... the first 100 object was deallocated (so the memory is free) or I must do [mutablearray release] to free memory?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if mutablearray is retained or using through copy property then surely you need to release it. And if you are not using mutablearray as property then you will need to look into the following:
Adding an object to an NSMutableArray increases it's retain count by one, giving it a retain count of 2 (1 for the alloc/init, and one for adding to the array).

so removeAllObject will take care of increased retaincount for the array and you need not to worry. Just call:

`[mutablearray removeAllObjects];`

Comment: If you are releasing the array, there is no need to call `removeAllObjects`.  Also, the absolute value of retina counts is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You need or remove all objects from your array. In this case you don't need new array.
Or release array, at release array releases all it's objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [mutablearray release] to free memory because releasing the objects doesn't release the internal structures of the array.
Also, you shouldn't release objects in the array, instead remove them from the array by using any of the remove... commands of NSArray

Comment: Or just release the array;  when the array is deallocated, it'll release all objects within it.